# Empty strings in array after using the split method with a regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm reading through Chapter 5 of *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers* and came across this example involving the split method and a regular expression. My confusion stems from the output of the variable colors3. Why does the array contain an empty string before and after the commas?

```
var colorText = “red,blue,green,yellow”;
var colors1 = colorText.split(“,”); //[“red”, “blue”, “green”, “yellow”]
var colors2 = colorText.split(“,”, 2); //[“red”, “blue”]
var colors3 = colorText.split(/[^\,]+/); //[“”, “,”, “,”, “,”, “”]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last case, you're defining separator as "any run of characters that aren't commas".

Because nothing precedes the first "separator" ("red") and nothing follows the last "separator" ("yellow"). `Split` presumes that the first separator is preceded by a value, and that the last separator is followed by a value -- as they are, in your first and second examples, and in any normal case such as a line in a CSV file. The only quasi-exception would be if the first (or last) value in the CSV line were an empty string; in that case, what would you see if there were an empty string followed by a separator?

You would see just a seemingly orphaned separator at the beginning of the line (or a separator at the end). It has to be this way because you have to support empty values.

If you preceded "red" with a comma, you would see an initial empty string in the first array, and an initial comma in the last.

I think you're thrown off by the fact that your last regex redefines "separator" as a set of characters normally regarded as data, and redefines "data" as a character normally defined as a separator.

Accept the arbitrariness. Let it flow through you. They're not commas and letters, they're zeroes and ones.